# EF6: ObjectContext.ExecuteStoreQuery returns empty List

Tags: c#, sql-server, entity-framework

I have following situation:

In the database:

- Stored procedure: gp_get_location
- In my Project (EF6) i have an DbContext object

  ```
  public List<Location> GetLocation(int LocationId, int Top = 100)
  {
      var prmLocationID = new SqlParameter("location_id", SqlDbType.Int)
      {
          Value = LocationId
      };

      var prmTop = new SqlParameter("top", SqlDbType.Int)
      {
          Value = Top
      };

      ((IObjectContextAdapter)this).ObjectContext.CommandTimeout = 300;

      var query = ((IObjectContextAdapter)this).ObjectContext.ExecuteStoreQuery<Location>(@"EXECUTE [dbo].[gp_get_location] @location_id, @top", prmLocationID, prmTop);

      return query.ToList();
  }
  ```

Executing the stored proc in the managment studio like this:

```
exec gp_get_location X, 100 -- returns 100 results

exec gp_get_location Y, 100 -- returns 100 results
```

Executing the context function:

```
GetLocation(X, 100) //returns 100 results

GetLocation(Y, 100) //NOT CORRECT - returns 0 results, no exception no warning just 0
```

What could be the reason for this strange behaviour and how can i trak it to the root ?

Answer (score 1):

This is a very old question that doesn't look like it was ever answered.  I'm assuming that you got it fixed, but just in case, check your Location object.  Make sure the members are Properties not Fields.